# SQL Datetimeoffset Compare

Tags: sql, datetimeoffset

I have a table storing a time value say "11:00 AM". This is what the client's would want the progress to run every day. The client also has a timezone info table letting me know which time zone its office is located. So "11:00 AM" in Eastern time zone is very different from "11:00 AM" in Pacific.

Then I have a program that checks whether the current time is what the client's desired runtime. This process runs in Eastern time zone always.

I am trying to figure out an easy way to compare whether my current time is actually the client's desired run time. What I am doing now is something like this:

1. Get the current DateTimeOffset of my environment. This will produce something like '2021-03-15 16:02:22.3112948 -04:00'
2. Then get the client's run time, which is "11:00 AM" or whatever the value, as well as client's timezone offset by using the sys.time_zone_info table. This give me the actual offset value, taking DST into consideration so that I don't have to calculate whether today is in DST or not.
3. I then construct a Datetimeoffset value from string by using current date value + client's run time value + the offset value. Then convert this into Eastern time zone using at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time'

By now, I have two values both in Eastern time zone and I can compare them. First question -- do you see any potential issue with my logic? Secondly, is there a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually just store the time as the UTC time in the database and convert on the client side from UTC>local or vice versa.  Why would you need to do the conversion in the database, if you store the run time as UTC in the database, that will be the run time.

Comment: I need to work with the data already in db. Also, the client's run time is not datetime, it's just a time value. It's supposed to run everyday, not a simple one time comparison.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to convert both dates to UTC and compare those? IF using SQL server 2016 and above you can use AT TIME ZONE for conversion.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference whether to convert both to UTC or use Eastern. In my first point, I obtained the current datetimeoffset, which is eastern. I can certainly convert that to UTC. But doesn't really change the logics much.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)